# Rock Paper Scissors Python Program: winOrLose() takes two arguments (0 given)

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I am writing a program that plays Rock Paper Scissors with the user. I have to run the program 5 times. And I am using python. Whenever I run the program and type in "R", "S", or "P", the program would result in an error:

```
TypeError: winOrLose() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)
```

This is my program below:

```
from myro import *  
from random import *  

def userOptions():  
    print "Press R for Rock"  
    print "Press P for Paper"
    print "Press S for Scissors"

choice = raw_input("Your choice is: ")

if choice == "R":
    return "Rock"
if choice == "P":
    return "Paper"
if choice == "S":
    return "Scissors"
else:
    userOptions()


def computerRandom():
    options = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
    cGuess = randint(0,2)
    return options[cGuess]

def winOrLose(userChoice, computerChoice):
    if userChoice == computerChoice:
        return "Tie"
    if userChoice == "Rock" and computerChoice == "Paper":
        return "Computer Wins"
    if userChoice == "Paper" and computerChoice == "Scissors":
        return "Computer Wins"
    if userChoice == "Scissors" and computerChoice == "Rock":
        return "Computer Wins"
    else:
        return "User Wins"

    while True:
        userChoice = userOptions()
        computerChoice = computerRandom()
        print "User Chose: ", userChoice
        print "Computer Chose: ", computerChoice
        result = winOrLose(userChoice, computerChoice)
        if result == "Tie":
            print "It is a tie"
        elif result == "Computer Wins":
            print "Computer Wins"
        else:
            print "User Wins"

def main():
    for index in range(1,5,1):
        speak("Rock Paper Scissors Shoot")
        userOptions()
        computerRandom()
        winOrLose()

main()
```

Please someone help me, I am kinda desperate at this moment to figure out how to fix this problem.

Thank you

Comment: Is this a question from the course on coursera- `Introduction to interactive programing in python` ? I seem to remember this

Comment: your winOrLose() function on last line of main function is the problem,give it 2 arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't pass it any arguments in your main function.

```
def main():
    for index in range(1,5,1):
        speak("Rock Paper Scissors Shoot")
        userOptions()
        computerRandom()
        winOrLose()
```

should be :

```
def main():
    for index in range(1,5,1):
        speak("Rock Paper Scissors Shoot")
        userChoice = userOptions()
        computerChoice = computerRandom()
        winOrLose(userChoice, computerChoice)
```

Another issue is that you try to run it 5 times with `for index in range(1,5,1)` but you got an infinite loop in you `winOrLose` functions so you won't ever exit that after calling it the first time:

```
def winOrLose(userChoice, computerChoice):
    if userChoice == computerChoice:
        return "Tie"
    if userChoice == "Rock" and computerChoice == "Paper":
        return "Computer Wins"
    if userChoice == "Paper" and computerChoice == "Scissors":
        return "Computer Wins"
    if userChoice == "Scissors" and computerChoice == "Rock":
        return "Computer Wins"
    else:
        return "User Wins"

    while True: # <=== infinite loop here.
        userChoice = userOptions()
        computerChoice = computerRandom()
        print "User Chose: ", userChoice
        print "Computer Chose: ", computerChoice
        result = winOrLose(userChoice, computerChoice)
        if result == "Tie":
            print "It is a tie"
        elif result == "Computer Wins":
            print "Computer Wins"
        else:
            print "User Wins"
```

The decision to play again most likely shouldn't be in the `winOrLose` function at all, it should be in it's own function.

You also got an indentation error in the `userOptions` functions although it might only be from copying it over here.

```
def userOptions():  
    print "Press R for Rock"  
    print "Press P for Paper"
    print "Press S for Scissors"
# below code block should be indented too.
choice = raw_input("Your choice is: ")

if choice == "R":
    return "Rock"
if choice == "P":
    return "Paper"
if choice == "S":
    return "Scissors"
else:
    userOptions()
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message tells you, you need to give two parameters to your `winOrLose` function. You return values from `userOptions()` and from `computerRandom()` but did not assign these values to any variables:

```
def main():
    for index in range(1,5,1):
        speak("Rock Paper Scissors Shoot")
        user_choice = userOptions()
        computer_choice = computerRandom()
        winOrLose(user_choice, computer_choice)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the error you are not passing the arguments to the function winOrLose
In your main function

```
def main():
    for index in range(1,5,1):
        ...
        ...
        winOrLose()     # in this statement you are not passing any arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling winOrLose() without any arguments although the definition says `def winOrLose(userChoice, computerChoice):`. You should put the values `userChoice, computerChoice`in the methodcall.